# Would having Angular tags in source code hurt SEO or would they just be ignored?

Tags: seo, html, angular.js

A developer wants to create an Angular site and of course still populate the page with HTML so the search engines can read the content.

In the source code there are Angular tags like in the screenshot below. In your opinion could these harm the SEO? Or will they simply be parsed like comments and ignored?

[image]